# Cannot report app crashes

Tags: google-play-store, crash-reports

In the rare event that I get an app crash notification (unfortunately "app" has stopped working), I am never able to report the event. When I press the report button, I get a second notification, this time that Play Store has stopped.

In all other respects Play Store works fine.

This sequence of events always occurs no matter what app originally crashed.

I have already tried clearing Google Play cache and data.  I tried removing its updates. I tried reinstalling its updates.

I am running Kitkat on an AT&T supplied Samsung Galaxy S3 mini. Kitkat was an AT&T push upgrade.

I keep some system apps turned off: notably just about anything starting with AT&T or Samsung.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It's not something you did. I experience the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to report crash, you can do using other way :

When app crash, go to

> Phone Dialer -> Dial *#9900# keystring -> Dial

This will open Dumpsys terminal, then click Run Dumpstate and this application terminal will capture logs in background for you.

Now, you just need to attach the file from /log/dumpstate_ddmmyyhhmmss file as crash report.

Comment: This answer could be improved. As it stands it is an incomplete replacement for Play Store based error reporting. I do not see how to be sure I am sending the right log, or how to actually deliver the log to the same destination that Play Store does.

Comment: Also it is not clear if this procedure actually captures the last crash, or the *next* crash, which would be quite different than what Play Store does.